# XML parsing using Elemetree in python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I am trying to read a XML file using python [ver - 2.6.7] using ElementTree

There are some tags of the format :

```
<tag, [attributes]>
....Data....
</tag>
```

The data in my case is usually some binary data that I read using text attribute.
However there are some cases where data can reference any other tag in the file.

```
<tag, [attributes]>
....Data....
<ref target='idname'/>
</tag>
```

What attribute from element tree can be used to parse them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [XPath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#elementtree-xpath) expressions.
This will tell you whether the  tag is present and, if present, returns the  node.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would use something like this:

```
for iteration in root.iter('tag'):
      if iteration.find('ref'):
             ...
```

So basicly I would parse thous cases separately.